# Credentials 'include' leads to failed to fetch (js/php)

Tags: javascript, php, cors, fetch-api

I've been trying to use [the Javascript fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to get out of my html/php routine for a javascript/php one.

I'm a bit confused, I've read many articles on this, and I think my problem comes from the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin. I tried many combinations possible, but still can't find a solution.

If I remove "credentials: "include"", my code works except that $_SESSION variable isn't saved in PHP (which is actually my main goal behind).

Here is the JS code running on 10.0.0.2 : 3000:

```
const fetchVar = (bodyVar, module) => {
fetch("http://10.0.0.3/index.php", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://10.0.0.3",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
    },
    credentials: "include",
    body: bodyVar
}).then((r) => {
    if(r.ok) {
        r.json().then((r) => {
            if(!r.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
                console.log(r);
            } else {
                console.log(r);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        console.log("error');
    }
});
}
```

Here the PHP code running on 10.0.0.3 : 80:

```
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://10.0.0.2:3000');
```

Both codes are longer, but I think this is where the issue comes from, because as I stated before, once credentials is removed, it works (works as well with "credentials: same-origin").

Thanks by advance for your answers :)

**EDIT:**

I added `mode: 'cors',` to my fetch script, and `header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');` to my php script. Thus I get a new error:

*Access to fetch at 'http://10.0.0.3/index.php' from origin 'http://10.0.0.2:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-credentials is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.*

SOLUTION:

Thanks to ADyson, here we are with the solution:

```
const fetchVar = (bodyVar, module) => {
fetch("http://10.0.0.3/index.php", {
    mode: 'cors',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json"
    },
    credentials: "include",
    body: bodyVar
}).then((r) => {
    if(r.ok) {
        r.json().then((r) => {
            if(!r.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
                console.log(r);
            } else {
                console.log(r);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        console.log("error');
    }
});
}
```

And:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://10.0.0.2:3000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: Since you have already set Access headers in PHP, do you need to send them again via JS `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://10.0.0.3", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"`? Since they are response headers and not request headers. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

Comment: Also since you are doing `credentials: "include",` might as well add `header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');`  along with `header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');` to your php

Comment: What specific problem are you having? Are you getting a CORS error?

Comment: Where do you set `bodyVar`?

Comment: Well to clarify, here I have two issues. The first one is that I don't get my $_SESSION saved through my differents fetchs. Thus I tried to fix it by adding "credentials: 'include'". But since I added it, I get a "TypeError: Failed to fetch...".
That's why I'm looking to headers in order to fix my credentials issue (failed to fetch then). I don't know if I'm clear enough.

I will try what you said Adi

BodyVar is actually a parameter I pass, but as I said before, this isn't the issue, because this part is working when credentials include isn't here.

Comment: Unfortunately Adi it didn't work

Comment: Remove `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://10.0.0.3",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"` from your JS code. These are supposed to be response headers, and make no sense in the client-side code - if the client could decide these things, then CORS would be completely pointless!  Additionally, one of them is explicitly the cause of the `Request header field access-control-allow-credentials is not allowed` error you've reported.

Comment: `mode: 'cors'` [is the default already](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode), so that won't have made any difference. `header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');` in the PHP makes sense, though.

Comment: Ok thanks ADyson! It works now! $_SESSION still doesn't work but at least Fetch yes! Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Great. Can't really tell you anything about your Session error though because your question doesn't contain a [mre] of that particular issue. Maybe start a new post about that

Comment: I won't disturb you more and just let you know that I'm taking care of this issue by myself, I don't really like to ask, but there I did because I'm not familiar at all with Javascript (and I don't even talk about fetching and headers...). I think now it is related to Set-Cookie same site or something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://10.0.0.3",         
"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
```

from your JS code. These are supposed to be response headers, and make no sense in the client-side code - if the client could decide these things, then CORS would be completely pointless!
Additionally, one of them is explicitly the cause of the

> Request header field access-control-allow-credentials is not allowed

error you've reported.